# C# Need to locate web addresses using REGEX is that possible?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, locate, webaddress

C# Need to locate web addresses using REGEX is that possible?

Basically I need to parse a string prior to loading it into a WebBrowser

```
myString = "this is an example string http://www.google.com , and I need to make the link clickable";

webBrow.DocumentText = myString;
```

Basically what I want to happen is a replace of the web address so that it looks like a hyperlink, and do this with any address pulled in to the string.  I would need to replace the web address so that web address would read like

```
<a href='web address'>web address</a>
```

This would allow me to have the links clickable.. 
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
new Regex(@"https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?").Match(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible depending on how strict or permissive you want your parsing to be.

As a first cut, you can try `@"\bhttp://\S+"` which will match any string starting with "http://" at a word boundary (non-word character, such as whitespace or punctuation).

To search using a regex and replace all occurrences with your custom text, you could use the [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) method.

You may want to read up on [Regular Expression Language Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) to learn more.